# Android app not showing in the device apps dashboard

Tags: android, manifest

My app doesn't appear in the apps dashboard and if I open it from the **Applications** list in the settings, the "start" button is disabled, I suspect is a misconfiguration in my AndroidManifest.xml but have no idea what exactly is wrong in it.

This is the code of my manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.designhunter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:host="auth-callback" android:scheme="designhunter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN) Action main does not expect to receive it data, but you have data tag. If you remove it (and the view action because it is required) it should work

Comment: In fact, I separated the main action and LAUNCHER category into its own intent filter and problem solved, thanks for your answer